# Qlikview Check for decimal points and load new column

Tags: sql, qlikview

I have this myCode column which consist of numbers in the format of eg 1, 1.2, 1.2.3

As you can see the maximum format is 1.2.3. There is no 1.2.3.4 etc

If the format has no decimal point, eg(1 or 2 or 15 etc), I would like to load a column called NEWCOLUMN which has a value of 'L1'. If the format has 1 decimal point, eg(1.2 or 1.3 or 5.4 etc), I would like to load a column called NEWCOLUMN which has a value of 'L2'.

If the format has 2 decimal point, eg(1.2.3 or 1.3.2 or 5.4.5 etc), I would like to load a column called NEWCOLUMN which has a value of 'L3'.

So my expected output would be

```
myCode                   NEWCOLUMN

1                               L1

1.1                             L2

1.4.7                          L3

1.5                              L2

8                                 L1
```

and so on.

What is the script to load this way? Im thinking something like

pseudocode

LOAD

IF(myCode has 2 decimal, 'L3' , IF(myCode has 1 decimal, 'L2', IF(myCode has 0 decimal, 'L1')) AS NEWCOLUMN

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your load script:

```
'L'&(substringcount(myCode, '.')+1) as NEWCOLUMN
```

For example will `'L'&(substringcount('1.4.6', '.')+1)` return `L3`